# I have been asked to restore an old Lamp website with Ubuntu 12 and no sudo access

Tags: upgrade, restore, usb-installation

I have prepared a USB with an Ubuntu 20 server iso, since I have been told that if I run this, it will update the software and recreate sudo access without deleting any of the old website.

I want to check that I am going down the correct path.

I normally run maintenance updates and backups on an established website and so this is a little outside my comfort zone.

Comment: Nice, but it is unclear what you actually want to do. There is Ubuntu 12 in your title, Ubuntu 20 in your question, none of which are known versions. So please update your question (use "edit") to clarify what exactly you want to do and what exactly you want to know.

Comment: "*I have been told that if I run this, it will update the software and recreate sudo access without deleting any of the old website.*" Perhaps...but if it goes wrong and deletes everything, who gets the blame? You, or whomever told you that? If it's you, then creating complete backup of the website data before starting seems wise. So does testing how to restore that backup into a website again using a disposable 20.04 Virtual Machine. Once you can handle the worst case scenario, you're ready to tackle the machine in real life.

Comment: Ubuntu 20?  There is no such release. Ubuntu uses *yy.mm* format (year.month of release) for all server & desktop releases, the *yy* being used only for IoT and specialist appliance/devices and cloud use  that can use *snap* packages only.  Please clarify which product you are using  (*year* only releases mean a different product since 2016)

Answer (score 0):

I would NOT try to install any new software/OS until you have a backup of the existing data. I don't think that upgrading from 12 to 20.xx is an option.

Booting to the bootable USB will allow you to mount the existing root partition and gain sudo access by editing the password,group and shadow files by hand.  If you are not confident doing this then I would suggest you find someone to help.

I agree with user535733, set up a VM and get your website up and running on that machine before changing the existing system.